# VBA Retaining Leading Zeros

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with retaining leading zeros in my document.

First of all I use Vlookup as below:

```
    aba = Application.VLookup("Routing/ABA/Sort Code:", Sheets("temp").Range("A1:B20"), 2, 0)
```

Then I need to put results into another sheet:

```
    Sheets("List").Range("B35") = aba
```

However even though the ABA code in the temp sheet is for example "0001", the destination sheet shows it as "1". I've seen some attempts in setting up custom number format, however numbers of zeros might vary in my case and this way doesn't work.

Is there a way to move the original number EXCATLY THE SAME to another sheet retaining all the leading zeros?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `Find` and copy the cell (including number format). `VLookup` doesn't return formatting

Comment: @BigBen Yes! That is what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Format the cell as string/text, not number. You can do that programmatically by adding a leading `'` sign to the value.

```vb
Sheets("List").Range("B35") = "'" & aba
```

Comment: Great idea, thanks! Works fine, however I ended up using Find and changing Number Format to Text